# SSH Port Forwarding from gcloud to my laptop behind NAT router

Tags: ssh, gcloud, portforwarding

I have my ubuntu installed laptop on which website is running on the localhost. The problem is I don't have public IP. I have tried forwarding port through my public IP shown on `whatsmyip` but it doesn't work.
so the solution is to forward the port through my `gcloud` VM instances which has ubuntu 18 running and have public IP to my laptop which has a website running on localhost. so to do that let's say the public IP of my `gcloud` instances is `12.12.12.12` so to forward a port from my `gcloud` instances to my laptop I have to run a command on the terminal of my laptop like this

> ssh -R 3245:localhost:80 12.12.12.12

I have saved the ssh key to `gcloud` of my local machine so don't have to type username when connecting to my `gcloud` machine.
from my understanding, if I open the public IP of my `gcloud` instances with port 3245 it should redirect to my laptop localhost with port 80 and should open my website but that doesn't happen.
tell me what I did wrong and help me, please.

what i did so far saved config file of ssh with `gatewayports` yes and `tcpforward` yes.
don't want to use `ngrok` and `localtunnel`.

Answer (score 0):

If your laptop is connected to the internet, it has a public IP. Try your IPv4 address. If that still doesn't work, you likely have a firewall on the router or on the laptop blocking the incoming connections. You'll need to enable port forwarding on your router.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to move your website to the GCP instance, you can transfer the files with cp command.

About connecting your laptop website to your personal public IP, this is possible, but you need to access who reaches the internet for you, your router, that usually has the private IP 192.168.1.1, your router is the one having the public IP. Then you need to know who private IP your router has given you running `ip -a` in your Linux laptop. Then in the router parameters you put that every request made to your Public-IP with port 80 (http), for example, should be forward to your laptop Private-IP x with port x, for example `192.168.1.20:80`. See [here](https://www.noip.com/support/knowledgebase/general-port-forwarding-guide/) for router configurations.

About showing your laptop to the internet using a GCP instance through SSH. I recommend you to use `ssh -L local_port:remote_address:remote_port username@server.com` for the remote_port you need to ensure that this port is open in your router, and that the port used to send the request from the rooter to the laptop is also opened in your Ubuntu system. Please refer to [SSH Tunneling](https://www.howtogeek.com/168145/how-to-use-ssh-tunneling/).